# Why Wheezy does not login after uninstalling pavucontrol

Tags: debian, login, mate-desktop, audacious

I had installed `PulseAudio Volume Control` and `audacious` on wheezy. I used the `HDMI` cable to view a video file via TV. After I removed the cable, audacious stopped responding and hanged and because I don't still know how to kill a program or process I just restarted the system. Now Debian starts and shows the login screen but  after logging in, it shows the login screen again. I used the recovery mode to remove both the applications but not any difference is occurred and I don't know how to fix my problem and log in.

Comment: I think the problem is caused because of my ignorance about how Linux works. I deleted my Debian and installed Ubuntu Mate and the same problem has occurred again and I think it is because I didn't log in to the x windowing system first. I pressed Ctrl + Alt + F1 and to exit the terminal that was opened I issued the command 'sudo shutdown -r now'. I now have no access to my desktop environment (login via login form is not successful).

Comment: As I have found the solution to the same problem in Ubuntu I think it will be useful on Debian too. The link to it is here :     http://askubuntu.com/questions/782993/why-ubuntu-does-not-log-in-to-x-windowing-system/783011#783011

Comment: Just to make sure: did that solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, I am using the system with no problems right now.